# Hi all, I wants to arrange my events(y) smallest to largest based on time(x). but I want this is as a loop

Tags: r

```
x = c(12,34,5,6,7)
y = c("A","B","C","D","E")
for(i in 1:length(x)){
    i = which.min(x)
    d = x-x[i]
    j = which.min(d[d>0])
    fevent = i
    nevent = j
    print(fevent)
    print(nevent)
    x = x[-i]
    y = y[-i]
}
```

### Output

fevent    nevent
C         D
D         E
E         A
A         B

Comment: Consider using the built in `order()` function. It works flawlessly and it is optimized for speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are after

```
> y[order(x)]
[1] "C" "D" "E" "A" "B"
```

---

If you want the code in terms of loop, I would suggest the `while` loop

```
while(length(y)>0) {
  i <- which.min(x)
  print(y[i])
  x <- x[-i]
  y <- y[-i]
  j <- which.min(x)
  print(y[j])
}
```

which gives

```
[1] "C"
[1] "D"
[1] "D"
[1] "E"
[1] "E"
[1] "A"
[1] "A"
[1] "B"
[1] "B"
```

---

If you want to save the output, you can try the code below

```
fevent <- nevent <- c()
while(length(y)>0) {
  i <- which.min(x)
  fevent <- c(fevent,y[i])
  x <- x[-i]
  y <- y[-i]
  j <- which.min(x)
  nevent <- c(nevent,y[j])
}
out <- cbind(fevent = fevent[1:length(nevent)],nevent)
```

which gives

```
> out
     fevent nevent
[1,] "C"    "D"
[2,] "D"    "E"
[3,] "E"    "A"
[4,] "A"    "B"
```

Comment: Thank you and How can I store those output in a table? or data frame like column1 - fevent: C, D, E, A column2 - nevent D, E, A, B

Comment: It's fine but NA values replace the D, I mean First event is C then D 5th row no need. second column shift up omitting NA and remove B from fevent column